# Image does not display material card

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, styles

I want to display the profile image in my project. but the image is not displayed and it shows alt word.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
        <mat-card class="example-card">
          <img mat-card-image src="..\assets\images\signupbg.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
          <mat-card-header>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
              <mat-card-title>Samanthika Rajapaksa</mat-card-title>
              <mat-card-subtitle>University of Moratuwa</mat-card-subtitle>
            </div>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>
            <mat-chip-list aria-label="Languages">
              <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Networking</mat-chip>
              <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Angular</mat-chip>
              <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Aws</mat-chip>
              <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Spring Boot</mat-chip>
              <mat-chip color="primary" selected>My SQL</mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try `src="assets/images/signupbg.jpg"` for image and `style="margin: 0 auto;"` on mat-chip-list tag.

Comment: @kian image not showed

Comment: Be sure your image source is correct and serve application again!

Comment: Please try using img tag like this "<img mat-card-image>"  @SamanthikaRajapaksa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the path written way. Try as given below.

```
<img mat-card-image src="assets/images/signupbg.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
```

Assumed as your `assets` folder is inside the `src` folder.